# Пользовательский стиль для кнопки

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-шаблоны, wpf-стили

Работаю над одним проектом в WPF, требуется написать стиль и шаблон для кнопки по макету. Для этих целей использую Blend для Visual Studio 2013. Вот мой шаблон :

```
<Style x:Key="FinPlanButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="10">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF98D3B"></SolidColorBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Кнопка :

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource FinPlanButton}" Content="Get Info" Width="571" Height="103.547"/>
```

Как видите, свойство контент не пустое однако на кнопке его не видно :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Вопрос - что я сделал неправильно ?

Comment: Фон можно задавать просто: `<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="#FFF98D3B">`.

Comment: @VladD, подозреваю, что это дело "рук" блэнда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стиле вашей кнопки не хватает элемента, который будет этот контент отображать, добавьте в `Template` `ContentPresenter`, например:

```
...
                    <Border CornerRadius="10">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF98D3B"></SolidColorBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал об этом!

Comment: А с TextBox так же работает ?

Comment: Для `TextBox` добавьте в шаблон `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>`

Comment: Интересно, почему именно `PART_ContentHost` иначе не работает

Comment: Так устроен TextBox, он ищет этот элемент в шаблоне по имени. Вместо `ScrollViewer` можно использовать любой декоратор, например, `Border`

Comment: Очень интересная подробность! Если знаете ссылку на статью или мануал который ее пояснит подробнее буду очень признателен.

Comment: @Сергей, лично я смотрю стандартный стиль и пробую, а вообще есть такие ссылки, например: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752068(v=vs.110).aspx